# How to skip NaN when using Math.min.apply?

Tags: javascript

To get the smallest number in an array of numbers, I use this:

```
var smallestNumber = Math.min.apply(null, arrayOfNumbers.map(function(x) { return x; }));
```

but if one of the numbers is NaN, smallestNumber returns NaN. Same thing happens with the max operator. (I might have Infinity but I am not sure if it gets returned)

How do I skip all the NaN's and return the smallest number?

Comment: That `.map()` call returns a copy of the original array ...

Comment: `array.map(function(x) { return x; })` does approximately nothing.

Comment: I usually prefer `Array.prototype.reduce`, as you could run into issues with the number of arguments if the array is too large.

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain your judgment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filter out the `NaN` entries:

```
var smallest = Math.min.apply(null, arrayOfNumbers.filter(function(n) { return !isNaN(n); }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Following zzzzBov’s idea, you could also do this using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). This would allow you to skip on intermediary array that would be created from the filter:

```
var minReduce = function (a, b) { return (isNaN(b) || b > a) ? a : b };
var smallest = arrayOfNumbers.reduce(minReduce, Number.MAX_VALUE);
```

*(I only stored the function separately in a variable to make it more readable in the answer; you are free to use a an anonymous function within the reduce call itself.)*

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution Pointy provided but i find this one more accurate:

```
const applicableValues = originalData.filter(o => number.isInteger(o[propertyName]));

const minValue = Math.min(...applicableValues.map(o => o[propertyName]));
```